# Perfectly inelastic collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, definition

Why do bodies move with the common velocity after collision in a [perfectly inelastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision#Perfectly_inelastic_collision)? What can be the possible explanation for it? Why don't they just go in any arbitrary direction rather than going together ?

Comment: That is the definition of a perfectly inelastic collision.

Comment: That's a defining characteristic of  a completely inelastic collision.  The final object is at rest in the center-of-mass frame of reference.  *Why* the objects stick together ... that depends on the surface features, elasticity, etc of the individual objects.

Comment: Can you please write a detailed answer ?

Comment: Can you please first explain what an "inelastic collision" is for you? Because currently you are essentially asking why bodies in a collision after which they move with a common velocity move with a common velocity after that collision.

Answer (score 2):

A "purely inelastic collision" or "perfectly inelastic collision" is **defined** as one in which the bodies move as one in the aftermath.

Some reasons that is an interesting way to classify collisions include:

1. They are relative common in real situation, so we can learn something about the real world by understanding them.
2. The post-impact kinematics of these collisions can be understood entirely in terms of conservation of momentum.
3. These collisions convert the largest possible fraction of their initial kinetic energy to non-kinetic channels.

Now, it is reasonable to ask "Why?" conditions (2) and (3) are true.

For condition (2) the answer is that with only one set of kinematic variables in the post-collision system we only need to be able to find one velocity to understand how the system move.

For condition (3) the reason can be found by examining the collision in the center of momentum (or center of mass) frame of reference. Because the total momentum is zero and the bodies stick together the only possibility in that frame is that they are at rest, which means that they have zero kinetic energy and *all* the kinetic energy of the initial state has been converted to other channels.